#  OpenGl polygon rotation

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, polygon

I'm trying to implement a moving and rotating polygon in OpenGl and C++.
Movement and rotation are along the XZ plane(2D transformations only).
The polygon is defined by a centre point and a set of vertices whose coordinates are stored as offsets from the centre point.
The polygon is moved based on the user's key-press either in X or Z direction by simply adding the moved distance to the centre point and updating the vertices by adding the offset values to centre coordinates. 
Rotation with respect to centre point is implemented by using the glRotatef() function.
But i need to know the coordinates of vertices for collision detection calculations.
Is there any chance of just retrieving the vertex coordinates of the transformed polygon without performing matrix operations myself?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any chance of just retrieving the vertex coordinates of the transformed polygon...

OpenGL is not a math library. It's only meant for drawing. Also the matrix manipulation functions of fixed function OpenGL are obsolete and have been removed from OpenGL-3 core and further.

> without performing matrix operations myself?

In fact, this is the recommended way to do this. Remember: OpenGL is just your drawing tool, not a 3D-renderer-game-simulation-engine-math-geometry-toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

The glRotatef function creates a matrix which is multiplied with the current matrix that exists on the stack to get the rotation on screen. Even if you could obtain that matrix then you would still have to multiply it against your vectors to obtain the values you want, which is what you'd have to do if you did the maths yourself. Just like datenwolf said, it would be better for you to make a maths library yourself that will perform all the necessary things needed for manipulating objects in a 2d or 3d world.